# NullPointerException when Navigating from AppWidget to Activity via PendingIntent

Tags: android

Ok i have been having this issue for a while now and i seem to be missing something. I have an appwidget which i update periodically via a service and in that appwidget, i navigate to an activity through a PendingIntent. 
 so in my appwidget, i have this:

in MyService class:

```
PerformMethod();

     /*do some other operations*/

    /*Display Forecast Details View*/
    Intent myactivity = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class );
    myactivity.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

    /*Utilising pendingIntent class to get Activity*/
    PendingIntent myactivityIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myactivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    /*Listener and updating appWidget through remote Views*/
    remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.settings_image_id, myactivityintent);


    public void PerformMethod(){

     dataset = MyDataSet.getDataSet();
      dataset.getDetails.clear();  // clear to get fresh values 

      details = new Details();

      dataset.setDetails(details);

      //perform other operations with details and add to the dataset.
    }
```

MyDataSet class:

```
 MyDataSet dataset; 

          private DataSet(){

    }

    public static synchronized MyDataSet getDataSet(){
        if(dataset == null){            
            dataset = new MyDataSet();
        }
        return dataset;
    }

    private ArrayList<Details> mydetails = new ArrayList<Details>(5);

        public void setDetails(Details details) {
        this.mydetails = details;   
    }

    public Details getDetails(){
        return mydetails;
    }
```

MyActivity:

```
MyDataSet dataset;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "on create of fragment activity");
    setContentView(R.layout.details_item_layout);

    dataset = MyDataSet.getDataSet();
    int count = dataset.getDetails.size();   // NullPointerException here
}
```

Now the issue is sometimes when i navigate to MyActivity from the appwidget, i get the values and sometimes i get Null. when i click the appwidget, the service might not have been updated because the timer has not triggered but MyDataSet is a singleton so am i not supposed to have some values there whether old or not. what am i missing in this case?..

Comment: Can you override your application class and override its onCreate method, chances are that you get null values when the whole application process is killed. Your design choices would not be robust to this.

Comment: @Snicolas sorry for the late response but if the application process is killed, shouldn't everything in the app stop working all together, Because when i debug the app, it shows the service class is constantly being updated periodically

Comment: It depends, the service can be restarted automatically if sticky.

Comment: @Snicolas, ok, so i should move all the code from MyDataSet Class to the Application class right?

Comment: No, I suggested you to create an application class and override its on start method. If you do so, you can log when application (re)starts. If that is the problem then you will see that each application restarts reset your dataset. And then we can fix the bug, bu first identify it.

Comment: @Snicolas oh great!... good idea, will try that and let you know because it seems difference processes are being triggered.

Comment: @Snicolas sorry to bother.. but yeah.. the Application OnCreate Keeps getting called whenever i Navigate to the Activity from the AppWidget. Seems i have GhostIds interfaring with the process.

Comment: That's pretty normal. And even, you are lucky to observe it during development, and not only when it would have crashed a user app in the wild... :) See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to make a widget and your app communicate via a shared static reference to your DataSet instance. This can't work well. It can work, but sometimes only.

Widget are displayed inside a special process on android. Let's call it Home.
Your app, including activities and services, is gonna be run in its own process. Let's call it the app process. Note that it's also possible to get a service in its own process, but that doesn't matter here.

What happens is that, while your widget is displayed, you can have no guarantee that your own app process is running or not. That's by design on Android : processes get killed by the system when needed, that's it. If so, your dataset class will get killed as well, it will no longer exist and will be garbage collected.

So if it gets killed, it will restart when your pending intent is executed, and it will just recreate everything, included your dataset, and everything in that class will be reset.

So, put in a few words, what you wanna do can't be done this way. It can work, but it will never be reliable, and you are pretty lucky to have observed it in an early development stage.

The solutions are :

- either store that permanently in a file / shared preference / database
- pass everything needed to your activity inside the pending intent. In that case, you will have to make your data parcelable or serializable and put it all inside the bundle passed to the intent of the pending intent.

Personally, I would suggest the second approach. It's more clear that this information is just meant to be passed to the activity, no need to put it somewhere where everyone can access it..

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I ended up passing everything to the pending Intent. Thanks once again

Comment: My pleasure. I am working hard to be an unsung hero on SOF :)